# Lizard Men from Space Invade Earth

Tags: story-identification, alternate-history

Sometime around 2005 to 2007 I read a book that told the story of an alternate history Earth that took place around World War 2. This book was part of a series but not the first or last book (I only read this one). The premise was that aliens (a race of lizard people) were invading Earth.

Points I remember:

- The aliens had sent a probe to Earth during the middle ages. They decided to send an   invasion fleet because at the time humans were at a very low level of technology. The aliens were surprised that humans had advanced so much in the intervening centuries because all other races they had encountered (including their own) moved at a very slow pace.
- The United States nuked Chicago to try and drive the aliens back.
- The aliens had taken custody of a new born from south-east Asia in an attempt to learn more about humans.

I'd really like to find out who wrote the series or what the title(s) are so that I can read all of them.

Comment: Alternate history? But lizard people [*have* invaded Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Icke#Reptoid_hypothesis)!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The series you are thinking of is called "[Worldwar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldwar)" by Harry Turtledove.

> The premise of the series is an alien invasion of Earth in the middle of World War II. The military invasion begins on or around May 30, 1942, but the aliens, who call themselves the Race, reached Earth orbit in December 1941. Presumably, six months were spent making preparations for the attack.
>
> Although the Race, a reptilian species, has the advantage of superior technology, their last information on humans was collected by a robotic probe during the 12th century. Their technology is only marginally ahead of 21st century Earth technology, and much of their equipment relies on basic principles still in use.

The 4 books in the series are:

1. Worldwar: In the Balance
2. Worldwar: Tilting the Balance
3. Worldwar: Upsetting the Balance
4. Worldwar: Striking the Balance

Comment: The series is quite good. Not as thought-provoking as *The Guns of the South*, but it's very readable and fun. There are also three additional books in a sequel series and a final epilogue book.

Comment: There is actually a sequel trilogy to WorldWar series, IIRC called Colonization.

Comment: The premise is so funny!  Middle of WW2 and aliens invade!  Could you pick a worse time to invade?  Just as all of the planet is scaling up its industrial might, and doing research and development on a level never seen again in the world.